# Connect a HashMap's key and value to a list

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I want to connect a `HashMap`'s key and value to a string with ':', and transform them to a list.

Example:

```
Map<String,String> tags = new HashMap<>();
tags.put("k1","v1");
tags.put("k2","v2");
```

then I want to get the string

> k1:v1,k2:v2

my code is:

```
private String transe(Map<String, String> tags) {
    if (tags == null || tags.isEmpty()) {
        return DEFAULT_STATUS_GROUP;
    }
    List<String> tagKVList = new ArrayList<>();
    tags.forEach((key, value) -> tagKVList.add(String.join(":", key, value)));
    tagKVList.sort((tag1, tag2) -> tag1.compareTo(tag2));
    return tagKVList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

How can I remove the local variable `tagKVList` and make the code clearer?

Comment: Lambda expressions are a nice feature, still you don’t need them to specify redundant things. `String`s are `Comparable`, that’s why they have the `compareTo` method, so you don’t need to specify a `(tag1, tag2) -> tag1.compareTo(tag2)` comparator. You can just use, `tagKVList.sort(null)` or, if you like type safety, `tagKVList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the intermediate `List`. You can `Stream` the `entrySet`, `map` each entry to a `String` and `collect` to a single `String` as you already do :

```
return tags.entrySet().stream()
                      .map(e-> String.join(":", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                      .sorted()
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: The good old `e.getKey()+":"+e.getValue()` would do as well in place of `String.join(":", e.getKey(), e.getValue())`… Oh, and you forgot the `sorted()` step.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, I missed that step.